# Angular. Custom tag selector in ng-template

Tags: angular, angular9

I refactor a string. So that why I need a component for it with `ComponentFactoryResolver`:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[text-in-message]',
  template: `<ng-template chunk></ng-template>`,
})
export class TextInMessageComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() message: string;
  @ViewChild(ChunkInMessageDirective, { static: true })
  chunkOfMessage: ChunkInMessageDirective;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}
```

The problem is, that, when I use `viewContainerRef.createComponent` it create `div` block. And, in my case, I need some `inline` element, like `span`. I tried `styles: [':host{display: "inlilne"}'],` but it don't work. How I can set a tag to created component or bind style?

Also, in this componen I have methods:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.refactorText();
  }

  refactorText() {
    const { viewContainerRef } = this.chunkOfMessage;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    const textNodeFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      TextNodeComponent
    );
    const textNodeComponentRef: any = viewContainerRef.createComponent(
      textNodeFactory
    );
    (textNodeComponentRef.instance as TextNodeComponent).text = this.message;
  }
```

Also `TextNodeComponent` if someone needed. It can have a random template.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[text-chunk-in-message]',
  template: `{{ text }}`,
})
export class TextNodeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() text: string;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

In result I got:

```
<div text-chunk-in-message="">A mere glimpse of Chuck Norris bearded member gave engineers the idea for the Alaska Pipeline.</div>
```

But I need `span` instead of `div`

Comment: `createComponent` does not create a `div` block. Also in the code you poste, you do not seem to use this method. You should probably post more information about what you are trying to achieve, so that we can get the complete picture

Comment: @PierreDuc post updated

Comment: It feels like you are trying to do something, which you should not be doing in Angular. If you think this is the way, can you show the template of the `TextNodeComponent`. Otherwise, can you try to explain what problem it is you are trying to solve with your solution?

Comment: @PierreDuc I trying to create string with mixed components. Template of `TextNodeComponent` can be random. Now it is just `{{text}}`. But I want to wrap it in `span` instead of `div`.

Comment: `TextNodeComponent` is a component, can you show me what the component definition looks like?

Comment: @PierreDuc `TextNodeComponent` added to question. But... it can have other template. I will use two or three generated components for text chunks. That why I want to wrap them in `span`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the selector of your `TextNodeComponent` to include the span:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'span[text-chunk-in-message]',
  template: `{{ text }}`,
})
```

This way it won't default to a `<div>`.

Working example:

[stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5aswfm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)